# Orchard translation of custom modules and texts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, translation, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I almost finished two Orchard projects and now I want to focus on translation.

Everywhere I used the Helper class `T("")` like `T("Some english text")`.

Is there a `Orchard 1.8` compatible module that lists all of my translation entries in the Admin menu and lets me create a new translation for it?

Or maybe any helper that lists the translations and writes it into a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module [Translation Manager](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Vandelay.Industries) (part of Vandelay Industries module in gallery) that can extract strings from source code and generate .po files.

[Docs: Contributing files for third party modules](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-global-ready-applications#Contributingfilesforthirdpartymodules)

> Contributing files for third party modules
>
> ... you can generate po files for it
>   using the Translation Manager module.
>
> From an Orchard command line, type the following command (for the
>   example of the Bing.Maps module):
>
> extract default translation /Extensions:Bing.Maps /Output:\temp
>
> This will create a new Orchard.en-us.po.zip file with the strings for
>   the module. The command looks at the source code for the module and
>   creates entries for T-wrapped strings, manifest strings and everything
>   that should be localizable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there no GUI based translation?

Comment: I'm afraid no. I've found some very old module that perhaps did what you ask for, but it certainly won't work on 1.8 without updating https://github.com/Q42/Orchard-DbTranslations ... You are better off generating the PO files and then use some GUI application to manage those PO files. It's fairly standard format.